# Migrating from material 2 to 3 causing issues. Changing theme causes app to crash

Tags: android, kotlin, material-ui, themes, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to android app development and am trying to develop using material 3 UI. However, as soon as I am chaning the base theme, I run the app, and on Android Studio it shows that it launches but then the app crashes as soon as it launches. Would really appreciate some help regarding this!

I tried to change the base theme and add several items under it but that did not work. I also tried different versions of Materia3 Base themes but not working

I went to themes.xml and added the following code to change the base theme

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

as per this documentation
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Comment: can you please share the exception message you're encountering? you can find it in the `run` tab at the bottom of android studio.

Comment: possible reasons behind the crash: trying to manipulate action-bar in java/kotlin file, not adding the latest material version in dependencies, not using proper sdk version etc.. the problem can be precisely identified using the log

Comment: @ganjaam, Apologies for the late reply. That is precisely the issue, when I run the app, the launch succeeds with no exception. But it crashes immediately upon running however no exception is generated.